# Error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement +++

Tags: c#

Me pasa este error cuando añado PlayerSkills(); pero no se lo que lo causa. No se si podria ser por el nombre o algo así, si podéis ayudarme.
Gracias

```
 void Start()
```

// Movimientos extra

```
    PlayerSkills();
```

---

```
 public void PlayerSkills()
{
    if (player.isGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
       fallvelocity - jumpForce;
       movePlayer.y - fallvelocity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola le tienes que poner = para asignar

```
fallvelocity -= jumpForce;
movePlayer.y -= fallvelocity;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.